# What's the difference between 創始者、創業者、創設者 and 創立者?

Tags: usage, words

I have seen 創始者 been used in the following contexts:
仏教の創始者、プログラムの創始者、儒教の創始者

創業者 probably refers to founders of businesses:
店の創業者、紀伊国屋の創業者

However, I only have a vague idea about how these are used.
Could anybody care to explain? :(

Comment: Related: [Difference between 創立、設立、樹立](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/517/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- 創始者 is a founder in intellectual terms, e.g.

  > 密教の創始者は空海です。
- 創業者 is the founder of a store or shop (related to work, rather than business), e.g.

  > 僕のおじいさんがこの魚屋の創業者なんだよ。
- 創設者 is the founder of a business/company, e.g.

  > ソニー株式会社の創設者は盛田昭夫と井深大です。
- 創立者 is the founder of a building/place (but could also be used for businesses, which would give it the nuance of associating the business with a place), e.g.

  > 高井戸小学校の創立者は山田景子です。

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Those example sentences really helped me understand the nuances perfectly!